# What is it that creates that wonderful smell after a fresh rain?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

I've heard that the wonderful smell of a fresh rain is actually chemicals  released from the trees and grass and other plants.

- What is the process that allows these chemicals to be released?
- What are the chemicals that create that smell?
- How is it advantageous for the plant to release the chemicals rather than hold onto them?

Comment: The fancy word for it seems to be petrichor. It has a nice wikipedia article which might lead you to some of the relevant publications. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrichor

Comment: Yeah, +1 and you go 2000+ :D *Petrichor* ;)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

That molecule is called [Geosmin](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1058374/). It is mainly produced <sup>1</sup> by *Actinomycetes* such as *Streptomyces* which are filamentous bacteria that live in soil. Other organisms also produce geosmin:

- [Cyanobacteria](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24289950)
- [Certain fungi](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307/3761199)
- An amoeba called [*Vanella*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1550-7408.1991.tb04798.x)
- A [liverwort](http://ci.nii.ac.jp/naid/40005331488/en/)

It is an intracellular metabolite and cell damage is the primary reason attributed to its release. However [oxidant exposure](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24289950) and [transmembrane pressure](http://dx.doi.org/10.2166/wpt.2010.049) also causes geosmin release in cyanobacteria. It seems that the release is triggered by some kind of stress.

I am not quite sure about their advantage to the host species.

---

<sup>1</sup> *or perhaps the most well-studied in*

Comment: Interesting answer!

Comment: What about Petrichor that @skymningen suggested in the comments?

Comment: @SolarLunix I guess that is the name of the smell, not the molecule itself

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on Petrichor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Petrichor) mentions geosmin, and indicates it is a compound different than petrichor.

Comment: @mgkrebbs Yes I checked that but I did not find much info on what petrichor really is. Moreover the wiki article does not have much info.

Comment: The aerosol generation by the rain droplet impact on wettable surface being the mechanism releasing geosmin from the soil into the air completes the story. The paper is at https://www.nature.com/articles/ncomms7083, together with a PDF version of the paper.